# Was the sacrifice invalidated because of Eli's sons?

Tags: kohen-priest

The sons of Eli treated the sacrifice with contempt and took it before it was cooked/burned.  This obviously was a sin against G_d but was the sacrifice invalidated to the one offering it?  If Joseph Blow came to offer a lamb to atone for a specific sin or purpose was that effort made null and void because the priest did not offer it correctly, or at all?

> **1 Samuel 2:15-16**
>   Yea, before the fat was made to smoke, the priest's servant came, and said to the man that sacrificed: 'Give flesh to roast for the priest; for he will not have sodden flesh of thee, but raw.' And if the man said unto him: 'Let the fat be made to smoke first of all, and then take as much as thy soul desireth'; then he would say: 'Nay, but thou shalt give it me now; and if not, I will take it by force.'<